# Getting a perfect output using .format()

Tags: python, file, file-io

Write a function called print_grades that accepts the name of a file (string) as input argument. Your function should call the function to read a file and create the grades dictionary. Using the grades dictionary, your function should print the names, grades, and averages of students with the exact format shown below. Notice that you are asked to write a function (NOT a program) and that function prints the grades. Your function should return None after printing the grades.

Sample Input file:

```
1000123456,Rubble,Test_3,80,Test_4,80,quiz,90
1000123210,Bunny,Test_2,100,Test_1,100,Test_3,100,Test_4,100
1000123458,Duck,Test_1,86,Test_5,100,Test_2,93,Test_4,94
```

Your program's output should be:

```
    ID     |       Name       | Test_1 | Test_2 | Test_3 | Test_4 |  Avg.  |
1000123210 | Bunny            |    100 |    100 |    100 |    100 | 100.00 |
1000123456 | Rubble           |      0 |      0 |     80 |     80 |  40.00 | 
1000123458 | Duck             |     86 |     93 |      0 |     94 |  68.25 |
```

Notes:

- Column titles are all centered
- The printed output is sorted in ascending order based on the student IDs
- Each column is seperated from a neighboring column(s) by three characters ' | ' (space vertical_bar space).
- IDs are always 10 characters and they are left justified (not counting the boundary characters)
- Names are left justified (maximum of 16 characters, not counting the boundary characters).
- Grades and averages are right justified. The width of the columns for the grades and averages is 6 characters (not counting the boundary characters).
- Averages are right justified with two digits of accuracy after the decimal point.

Code developed so far. And please tell me what to do next.

CODE:

```
def create_grades_dict(file_name):
my_dict={}
file_pointer=open(file_name, "r")
data = file_pointer.readlines()
for line in data:
    datalist = line.strip().split(',')
    if len(datalist) < 2: 
        continue
    stud_id, last_name = datalist[:2]
    namelist, gradelist = [], []
    for name in datalist[2::2]:
        namelist.append(name.strip())
    for grade in datalist[3::2]:
        gradelist.append(int(grade.strip()))
    namelist.append('avg')
    avg = sum(gradelist)/float(len(gradelist))
    gradelist.append(avg)

    newdict = dict(zip(namelist, gradelist))
    my_dict[stud_id]=[last_name, newdict]
    return my_dict
```

ERROR:

```
Error in evaluating function:
ValueError at line 7
too many values to unpack
```

Comment: You gave only six names to a line that has eight values.

Comment: your trying to split 8 values into 6 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this as you expected you need two functions:

First function:

```
def create_grades_dict(file_name):
    my_dictionary = {}
    file_pointer = open(file_name, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    for line in data:
        student_row = map(str.strip, line.strip().split(','))
        student_id = student_row.pop(0)
        student_lastname = student_row.pop(0)
        student_data = [student_lastname]
        for valid_test in ['Test_1', 'Test_2', 'Test_3', 'Test_4']:
            if valid_test in student_row:
                student_data.append(int(student_row[student_row.index(valid_test) + 1]))
            else:
                student_data.append(0)
        student_data.append(sum(student_data[-4: ])/4)        
        my_dictionary[student_id] = student_data
    return my_dictionary
```

2nd function:

```
def print_grades(file_name):
    # Call your create_grades_dict() function to create the dictionary
    grades_dict=create_grades_dict(file_name)
    print ("    ID     |       Name       | Test_1 | Test_2 | Test_3 | Test_4 |  Avg.  |")
    for key in sorted(grades_dict.keys()):
        print ("{0:<10} | {1:<16} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} | {4:>6} | {5:>6} | {6:>6.2f} |".format(key, grades_dict[key][0],  grades_dict[key][1],  grades_dict[key][2], grades_dict[key][3], grades_dict[key][4], grades_dict[key][5], ))
```

So you see second function call the first function and it gave the correct output:

```
 ID     |       Name       | Test_1 | Test_2 | Test_3 | Test_4 |  Avg.  |
1000123210 | Bunny            |    100 |    100 |    100 |    100 | 100.00 |
1000123456 | Rubble           |      0 |      0 |     80 |     80 |  40.00 |
1000123458 | Duck             |     86 |     93 |      0 |     94 |  68.25 |
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should keep in mind:

1. Your input line may contain junk data - data you need to ignore.
2. Your input file may have blank lines, which you need to test for.

Unpacking a variable requires a balance between the left and the right hand side of the `=` sign; if you have too many things on the right, and too few variables on the left, you will get:

```
>>> a,b,c = 1,2,3,4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Of course, if you have too many variables on the *left*, then you get a different error:

```
>>> a,b,c = 1,2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Try reading the entire line, and split by `,` (as you are doing now). Then, step through the list returned, and then separate your values - rather than assuming all the lines will have the correct information in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

As Burhan explained you the error. you can proceed like this:

```
a = "1000123456,Rubble,Test_3,80,Test_4,80,quiz,90"
>>> my_val = a.split(",")
>>> my_val
['1000123456', 'Rubble', 'Test_3', '80', 'Test_4', '80', 'quiz', '90']
>>> id,name = my_val[0], my_val[1]
>>> id
'1000123456'
>>> name
'Rubble'
my_dict = dict(zip(my_val[2::2],my_val[3::2]))
>>> my_dict
{'Test_4': '80', 'Test_3': '80', 'quiz': '90'}
```

NOW you can use `dict.get(key[,default])`

```
>>> my_dict.get('Test_4',0)
'80'
```